# I'm looking for a jquery form validation plugin, which can give validation error as a "Alert"

Tags: jquery, xhtml, accessibility, screen-readers

I'm looking for a easy to use jQuery form validation plugin, which give validation error as a **"Alert"**. Because **alert** is the best way to inform screen reader users about errors.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

```
$('form').validate({
              errorPlacement: function(error, element) {                
                 alert(error.text());
               }
          });
```

[Hosted by Microsoft](http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.5.5/jquery.validate.min.js).

`alert()` may be useful for screen readers (citation?) but they are frustrating for everyone else. Anyone else agree?

Comment: I think alert is the best way to inform about error to disabled users and it's also easy for people who like to use keyboard.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid It is also useful for people who like having their browsing experience stolen by an `alert()` :P

Answer (score 0):

Most of the validations plugins write out a summary of the issues onto the page.  You could do a simple code change in the plugin to just do an alert() versus jquery writing it using .html()

Shouldn't be too painful of a mod, and something small to have some fun modifying a plugin.